Datadog ingest only 1% of span, DD_SPAN_SAMPLING_RULES is not working
I am developing a microservice using ASP.NET Core. We are using Datadog.Tracer library for distributed traces & span. Currenlty it is collecting all the spans and traces. I only want 1% of spans to be collected and ingested. I am setting below environment variables, but it is not having any effect.
DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE: "0.01"
DD_SPAN_SAMPLING_RULES: '[{"sample_rate":0.01,"service":"*","name":"*"}]'

Why it is not sampling spans? What am I missing?

You could refer to this doc for some explanations https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_pipeline/ingestion_mechanisms/?tab=net&code-lang=dotnet. I cannot reproduce this issue as a default project locallly works as expected. In my research the environment variable settings could be a cause. I suggest you could start a brand new app in asp.net core to reproduce this and debug through the logs.

In microservice scenario, if upstream service is ingesting a span/traces then all the child span originating from all the downstream service are forced to be ingested.
